# Delete specific record from file of records

Tags: delphi

I have the next data structure :

```
 Type
 TMyRecord=Record
                 Num:String[50];
                 ID:String[50];
   
 End;
```

and I have a file of record Like the next :

```
Var
F:File of TMyRecord;
```

the file will contains many records , how I can delete one specific record from the file.

Thank you in advance .

Comment: The common method for fixed sized records is a deleted flag along with the other fields. Otherwise you have to re-write large portions of the file or shuffle records around to remove records.  Re-writing large portions is slow and shuffling doesn't work well for multi-user access.

Comment: Have you considered using an embedded DB like e.g. SQLite instead?

Comment: Am just asking about files only , database is not what am asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the record is at the very end of the file, you can simply truncate the size of the file to omit the record.

Otherwise, the only way to delete a record from the beginning/middle of the file is to create a new file, copy the existing records from the old file to the new file omitting the record you want to delete, and then replace the old file with the new file.

Comment: It seems to be the easiest way , but I was thinking about using seek function or loading all the records inside a list and then delete the record from the list and saving the list to the file. but not sure about my thoughts. :)

Comment: What you describe is basically the same as I describe, only you are thinking of saving the updated list to the existing file, whereas I suggest you save it to a new file first, in case something goes wrong.